# Android 6.0.1 eddystone beacon stopped scanning

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-6.0-marshmallow, eddystone, eddystone-url

My eddystone beacon application was perfectly working on Android 5.0 but after updating to Android 6.0.1 it is not scanning at all. Whereas same app is working on another phone having 5.0 version.

I have search on internet, found that there were some issue with BLE in Android 6.0. Also I followed some suggested fixes like turning on Location to get BLE scanning work or force to use old 4.x Bluetooth API instead of 5.x API
beaconManager.setAndroidLScanningDisabled(true);

But these wont help to get scanning in my case.

Its very appreciable if someone help me.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with Android 6, apps must dynamically request location permissions at runtime from a user before they are allowed to scan for BLE beacons.  If this is not done, scanning is blocked and no beacons will be detected.

See my blog post here for details:

http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/09/29/is-your-beacon-app-ready-for-android-6.html